# Windows - Direct2d or Direct3d for isometric games (2.5D games)

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, direct2d

I wanted to try and recreate a a small game that is no longer in development and I wanted to make sure I am learning the correct DirectX api. The game used sprites for all their animations if that helps.

Would I learn direct2d or direct3d for a game like this?
[image]

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the  [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). You can get a very long way with just ``SpriteBatch``. Direct2D is really more a [vector graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) API than a '2D game' API, although you can clearly use it for that.

Answer (score 2):

Direct3D with an orthographic projection matrix.  You could use 2D but the amount of extra sprite work for different viewing angles would be a pain.

Once you understand 3D you can apply the same knowledge to creating a 2D game by keeping the camera pointing forwards and give all your sprites etc a 0 z coordinate.

I'm a few months away from publishing a game on google play etc and trust me,
no such thing as a "small game" lol.

Good luck.